# TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, OS.PathLike or integer, not list?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm working on an NLP project and during word to vector transformation, I'm facing this problem.
Here is the code.

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec 
w2v_train = Word2Vec(min_count=2, corpus_file=train_corpus)  Can an
```

Comment: You need to show the data used in your code which isn’t a [mre] - for example you don’t initialise variables, and there is a mysterious syntax-busting `Can an` at the end of the second line; in this case, what is the value of `train_corpus`?

Comment: What is `train_corpus`? What is the full error, with any associated traceback info, you're getting?